# Custom error messages on coupon codes

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes, promotions, error-message

I want to get Custom Error Messages for invalid Promo Codes. To some extent I achieved by using this Extension
https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-couponerrormessage.html,
but I need to display the error message based on store view specific (I have 5 store views).

How I need to apply Store Id in the
`/V1/carts/{cartId}/coupons/{couponCode}` API Call and get store view based error messages.

Thanks in advance.